# Solidity: how to avoid variable shadowing

Tags: solidity

I'm trying to implement an ERC721 token minter but I am all the time getting the error of variable shadowing. This is the header of the code:

```
contract NFTMinter is ERC721, Ownable, ReentrancyGuard {
    using SafeMath for *;
    using SafeERC20 for IERC20;
    using Address for address;
    using Strings for uint256;

    // Token name
    string private _name;

    // Token symbol
    string private _symbol;

    // Mapping from token ID to owner address
    mapping(uint256 => address) private _owners;

    // Mapping owner address to token count
    mapping(address => uint256) private _balances;

    // Mapping from token ID to approved address
    mapping(uint256 => address) private _tokenApprovals;

    // Mapping from owner to operator approvals
    mapping(address => mapping(address => bool)) private _operatorApprovals;
```

Does anybody can help please? how can I correctly access parent contract state variables ? When I comment them compiler says that there are references to non-existent variables or functions...

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming that you're extending OpenZeppelin's contracts. I think you need to read about how to properly extend contracts in Solidity. You don't need to define most of those private variables you have there, as you already have those from the contracts you're extending.

When you extend a contract in Solidity, then all the storage variables and functions that are defined in that contract become part of the contract you're writing.